# Opam switch install could not install the older version of ocaml (3.08.3)

Tags: ocaml, resolve, opam

I'm doing some works with ocaml and opam.
I need ocaml of version 3.08.3, so I tried install this version via opam.
`opam switch install 3.08.3` 
The above command would install it successfully, I hoped. But it couldn't.
opam-switch could not install 3.* versions of ocaml with the following error message.
`[ERROR] Could not resolve set of base packages`
I searched this message everywhere, but I couldn't get any of hints. Does anyeone have a clue to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`compilers/3.08.3/3.08.3/3.08.3.comp`, the file to describe the base packages for that compiler version tells:

```
packages: [
  "base-unix"
  "base-bigarray"
  "base-threads"
  "base-ocamlbuild"
]
```

So it requires `base-unix`, `base-bigarray`, `base-threads` and `base-ocamlbuild`.  However, the package description of `base-ocamlbuild`, `packages/base-ocamlbuild/base-ocamlbuild.base/opam` says:

```
ocaml-version: [>= "3.10" & < "4.03"]
```

It says that `ocamlbuild` is not available before `3.10`.  Indeed, `ocamlbuild` was introduced since 3.10.  It is likely that the compiler description file `3.08.3.comp` has a bug.  It is great if you would raise a bug ticket at https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository/issues for the fix.

For a workaround, I recommend to install OCaml 3.08 by hand, not using OPAM command: I see almost no benefit to use OPAM with 3.08 where `ocamlbuild` is not available, since most of the OPAM packages assume the existence of `ocamlbuild`.

You could also create your own copy of OPAM repo with a fixed `3.08.3.comp` file without `"base-ocamlbuild"`. See the document of `opam repo` for more details.